# SQL Transaction statement not working in Xampp

Tags: mysql, transactions

I was trying to commit a transaction in Xampp. The SQL is as follows:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE accounts
   SET balance = balance - 1000
 WHERE account_no = 100;

UPDATE accounts
   SET balance = balance + 1000
 WHERE account_no = 200;

INSERT INTO account_changes(account_no,flag,amount,changed_at) 
values(100,'-',1000,datetime('now'));

INSERT INTO account_changes(account_no,flag,amount,changed_at) 
values(200,'+',1000,datetime('now'));

COMMIT;
```

The error is at line 1 as-
  BEGIN TRANSACTION [Unrecognized Keyword]
[[image: Transaction_Error]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMjs8.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such statement in MySQL as `begin transaction`. You can choose between `start transaction`, `begin`, or `begin work` to start a transaction. See MySQL documentation on [start transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) for further details.